# How to use resize event on CKEDITOR 4.0?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can i use the resize **event** of an CKEDITOR 4.0.

I need to set some properties while editor resizing. 
In CKEDITOR 4.0 API event is there.but i don't know how to use it.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to use it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
//After the editor instance created add the resize event
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(ev) {
    ev.editor.on('resize',function(reEvent){
         alert( 'The editor resized' );
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the `instanceCreated` event didn't work for me, but `instanceReady` did:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',function(ev) {
    ev.editor.on('resize',function(reEvent){
        //your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: Same for me. The doc says "To interact with a fully initialized instance, use the `instanceReady` event instead."